# Can pointers be safely and portably used as object IDs?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have a bunch of valid pointers to instances of a class `A`. Can I safely and portably assume that the pointers will stay the same during the whole object lifetime? In other words, can I use a pointer to an object as a unique object ID?

Comment: What do you mean "portably"? You're sending the value across systems?

Comment: @littleadv: He means "your answer should be relevant to all mainstream systems".

Comment: @Tom of course... time to go to sleep:-D

Comment: A GUID/UUID/statically incrementing ID may be a better option.

Comment: @DanDan: I'm actually already using a statically incrementing ID, but was wondering if I can get rid of the extra indirection layer.

Comment: @Arek' Fu: If it's not a bottleneck in your program, I'd keep it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure; I don't see why not.

A memory address is pretty much the definition of object identity (taking type out of the equation for a moment).

Comment: ...unless multiple inheritance is involved, in which case one object can have multiple addresses ;-)

Comment: @FredOverflow: I don't quite follow the argument: different subobjects of a given object will have different addresses, but the object will have a single address, regardless of multiple (and/or virtual inheritance)

Comment: @David: If you view a `Derived` as a `Base`, the object may have a different address. Not that it matters for typed pointer comparison, that will still work. But if you have a database consisting of `void*` pointers, you may get false negatives.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I know that, that is what I said: each `Base` subobject has it's own address, and that is what you get with the upcast, and it is a *different* object. If you want to compare pointers you have to do it with the same type, and the downcast (or upcast) will provide the same addresses. In particular the standard defines object in 1.8/1: *An *object* is a region of storage*, which means that a pointer to that region uniquely identifies it. You are mixing concepts, the fact that you can *upcast* to obtain a pointer to a subobject does not mean that the object has different addresses.

Comment: Up and downcasting do not yield pointers to the same object, but to the subobject (or super-object if that was a proper term) of the given type. The relation address -- object is unique **always**.

Comment: Just in case, upcasting can result in a pointer with the same (`void*`) value: for example in the case of _empty base optimization_.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily - it depends how you allocate those instances and what you then do with them.  For example, suppose that you create an array of objects and then reallocate that array.  There is now no guarantee that the objects will still reside in the same location.

Comment: Those aren't the same objects, they're copies or moves.

Comment: @DeadMG - I do not believe it's defined what realloc (for example) does when such a situation arises.  It might as easily be a bit-by-bit copy as opposed to the use of a copy constructor.  In the first case I think I would argue that it is the same object.

Comment: +1 This is actually correct, depending on how you store the objects, they might *semantically* move from one address to another. @DeadMG: If you store a string in a vector, and then store a few more strings and the vector reallocates, would you say that `v[0]` is no longer `v[0]`? According to the language they are not, but *semantically* they are exactly the same object. Now consider a user defined object with some state, that you decide to hold inside vectors...

Comment: @David: Are they really the same object? I think that they are equivalent, not identical.

Comment: @Tomalak: From the language point of view they are different elements, but from the semantics of a program, when you add an element to a vector as the first element and you later extract `v[0]` you are referring to the *same* object regardless of whether addition of other objects to the vector *moved* the object somewhere else. They *are* different objects, but they represent the *exact same* object in the domain. From the application perspective, the fact that it *moved* is an implementation detail, the entity that they are modeling is exactly the same, it *models* the *same* object.

Comment: ... programming is about modeling a reality, and in some designs, the modeled object can be represented by different C++ objects at different points in time, if that is the case, then you cannot use pointers as a unique identifier, as it may treat the same domain entity as a different object. Granted that the discussion can be seen at two different levels, in the language level you are right, they are different equivalent objects, in the domain they represent the same unique entity.

Comment: For an interesting example, consider implementation of a Java JVM in C++, when a generational moving GC moves the object from one place to another, the *object* in the C++ sense is different, but the *Object* in your Java environment is the same.

Comment: @David: OK, but that's hardly useful when programming.

Comment: @David, @Tomalak: looks to me to be just the difference between *object* identity and *value* identity. It may be that the questioner is interested in value identity, but all signs as far as I can tell, are that this question is about object identity. As such, a relocated vector element is *not* the same object any more. Of course it represents the same value. If your problem domain is modelled with values then it therefore represents the same entity in the problem domain, but "object" remains a technical term in the C++ domain, not the problem domain.

Comment: ... so, if you want to assign a GUID to each *entity*, then it must be copied by the copy ctor and copy assignment operator, and it's possible to have multiple objects with the same GUID if they represent the same entity in the problem domain. If you want to assign a GUID to each *object*, as apparently the questioner does, then you would generate a new GUID in the copy ctor and copy assignment operator. So it's trivial to tell the difference between the concepts as soon as you look at any code, it's only English that is potentially ambiguous ;-)

Comment: @borrible: Then again I don;t expect to see realloc() be used to move C++ objects because it will break them in most not trivial situations.

Comment: ... and the Java example is potentially confusing only because if you're implementing a JVM in C++, then "Object" is a technical term in the problem domain, in addition to "object" being a technical term in the programming domain. If you relocate a Java Object in the garbage collector, then you copy its identityHashCode to the new C++ object.

Comment: @Steve: Are you sure? :) He wants to replace a *statically incrementing ID*, that looks more like the model than the language layers. I.e. it is not that he wants to detect self assignment by checking whether the `rhs` is `this`, but rather a unique tag associated to the data, and unless the copy constructor generates a different tag, and the assignment keeps the old one, then the semantics will change. I don't know the requirements the he/she has, but I would not rule out that possibility.

Comment: I'm not *sure*, but when I say "all signs", I mean that the questioner repeatedly mentions "object ID" and "object lifetime". It's possible that the questioner is grossly absuing terminology, and by "object lifetime" in fact means "the duration of this object *and* all copies of it", and hence is completely barking mad to even dream of using pointer values, since clearly the address of a copy is different from the address of the original. But what the questioner actually *says*, is objects :-) It may be that the objects are not copyable and hence the two amount to the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can only do this if you are sure that no object will be created once an object gets deleted. The new object could be created at the same address of a previously deleted object, and this could be a problem: you don't want two different objects to have the same ID.

Answer (score 5):

While it is generally true that a memory address uniquely identifies an object. There are two important caveats:

1. When an object is deleted, the address may be reused (very possibly for an object of the same class).
2. If you are working with different processes, addresses may well be the same in the two processes.

Answer (score 3):

One worry (and it is a real worry) is cuckoo pointers.

Suppose you cache a pointer value A.

Then later free that pointer, then later allocate a new object B.

The memory allocator may choose the location that was used for A to allocate B.

Code of the form:
if (new_pointer != old_pointer) {...}

may fail to realise that the object has changed.

http://www.nobugs.org/blog/archives/2004/11/20/cuckoo-pointers/

Edit:

Another way to put this, your object while alive will always be at the same address, the object at that address however will not always be the object you expect.

Comment: If you free the pointer without nulling it out, then it's your own damn fault.

Comment: A codebase that allows non owning pointers would have a hard time nulling out all those copies of the pointer value.  As the question specified using pointers as a unique ID I felt this was a useful point to make.  Also it is a real bug I've seen more than once.

Comment: A codebase that allows non-owning pointers, and then uses those pointer values *for any purpose*, including comparison, after the allocation was freed, is broken. It's UB to use a pointer to freed memory, irrespective of whether you dereference it or not (and not just unspecified whether the comparison is surprisingly true due to recycling of the old memory by the allocator). So, while it's true that owners would "have a hard time" nulling out those copies, they nevertheless must somehow ensure that those copies will not be used in future.

Comment: Personally I prefer this to be due to logical inevitability (whatever variable or structure holds the pointer ends its life prior to or in effect at the same time as the memory is freed), rather than by actually going around writing null pointers everywhere.

Comment: I am confused - my answer was meant as an argument FOR defensive programming - I'm not advocating poor pointer patterns! All comments received seem to want to assume that all codebases are already well behaved - really? Should stackoverflow answers be made in that context?

Comment: @morechilli: my comment was supposed to be to the effect that because retaining old pointers is broken, if the questioner's code requires retaining the UIDs after the object might have been freed, then he can't use pointers. So I'm agreeing with your answer: dangling pointers are bad. I'm also slightly disagreeing with DeadMG's comment, in that I think most of the time we shouldn't be thinking about nulling out dangling pointers, we should be destroying whatever has the dangling value, or perhaps replacing it with a different object pointer. As a last resort, one might assign a null pointer.

Comment: @steve - ok i understand now - thank you - sorry for my confusion there

Answer (score 2):

So long as the object stays in memory and you always refer to the same instance (eg. you don't pass it by value and then compare that object to the original or another cached copy) the address will always stay the same, and the pointer is a reasonable ID. This is obviously true -- if the object moved in memory, the pointer wouldn't work any more, and the standard guarantees that pointers to different objects compare to different values. [This is why you can't have zero length objects, so the following object in memory has a different address.]

However, if the object will ever be passed across a network or saved to disk, obviously that won't work any more, and you'll have to compare the object element-by-element, or have it include a unique id value (aka primary key).

ETA: borrible is correct that if you realloc the memory containing the objects, the values will be different, but obviously the pointers won't be valid at all, so your program will be broken whether you expect the pointers to be unique or not. (Conversely, if you use smart points that will track reacllocs -- essentially how C# and .NET work -- the value will not necessarily be the same, but the values of the pointers will still be different between different instances of the object.) In fact, that's the rule -- so long as the pointers are valid, you should be able to compare them, but you can't cache the value and expect it to still work some undetermined time later (in case you destroy the object first), so if you're sure you won't, it's ok, but keep it in mind, often you WILL want to serialise the objects at some point, and then having designed them like that from the start will be better.

Answer (score 1):

If the pointers to different subclasses aren't c-cast to void*, then yes, no problem with comparing pointers to check if it's the same object.

In the case of storing the address as void* or uint values for ID purposes, there's a few less obvious problems that occur when a class inherits from multiple classes.

Consider class C which inherits from class A and class B. If class C is referenced via a class A pointer it will show equal to referencing the same object via a class B pointer.

```
C* c = new C();
A* a = C;
B* b = C;
a == b; // true
```

However, if you cast a C object from a class A pointer to a void pointer you may end up getting the sub object address, rather than the full object's address. The types will keep track of this in a normal case and it's only a worry when void pointers are used.

```
void* avoid = (void*)a;
void* bvoid = (void*)b;
avoid == bvoid; // false
```

To guarantee the proper address to the most derived and complete object, use dynamic_cast( myObject ). Remember though, that it must be a polymorphic class and RTTI must be enabled for dynamic_cast to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just going back a sec, someone said that polymorphism involves having multi addresses for one object?

I'm pretty sure, that this is what the virtual function table is for. Before `Object1->func1()` is called the type  and the address of `Object1` is used as keys to the vtable and an address for `func1()` is obtained. Right? Doing a recast, like back to the base class like:

```
BaseClass* OPtr = reinterpret_cast<BaseClass*>(DerivedObjectPtr);
OPtr->func1();
```

will make the key pair `address` + `type` different and can thus return different function pointers.

That is how I would write the runtime stuff anyway. Dont know about multiple inheritance though, which is an abomination imo. And I am also using object addresses as `ID`s. I can't really find any fault with it, can anyone else?

Answer (score -2):

If all instances of class A are stored in heap, yes, they'll remain the same for the whole program lifetime. If, instead, instances are created in the stack, then absolutely no, because at the end of the scope they get destroyed.

Comment: What? "the pointers will stay the same during the whole object lifetime" is absolutely true, then. No need to bring storage duration into it.

Comment: of course, but if they point to an object created in stack, the object will be destroyed at the end of the scope, so the pointer will not be valid anymore (in the sense that something else can be stored in that position)

Comment: Of course. The same is true for objects of dynamic storage duration (what you are calling "in heap"). Once an object is destroyed, its lifetime has ended, and the scope of the OP's question is fully satisfied.

Comment: Oh yes... I just thought Arek' Fu was talking about the program lifetime, not the object's one...